# Will gwibber be fixed to work with new twitter API

Tags: gwibber, twitter

Will gwibber be fixed to work with new twitter API as it was official twitter client for 12.04 LTS, or should we search for the twitter client that works with new API?
The fix is here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1190575

Comment: This is already in a bug report: [LP Bug #1190479 "Twitter auth does not work. API Change."](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1190479). Mark yourself as affected and subscribe to updates. That's your best bet for now.

Comment: What do you mean "The fix is here ..."? It's a link to a duplicate bug report of the one I linked. There is, however, reported a **workaround**. Do you mean [comment #6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1190575/comments/6) in that bug report perhaps?